# F#: Compose empty sequence without using Seq.empty

Tags: linq, f#, sequence, seq

I write my own reimplementation of LINQ using F# (thanks to Jon Skeet for inspiration).

I use a trick to generate empty sequence:

```
let empty<'b> =
        seq {
            for n = 0 to -1 do
                yield Unchecked.defaultof<'b>
        }

printfn "%A" empty<int> // -> seq []
```

Is there any idiomatic approach to do this?

(`Seq.empty` is not useful, I'm just reimplementing it)

Comment: why is `Seq.empty` not usefull while the `seq` builder is? Anyway you can always use an object-expression that returns an `IEnumerable<'b>` which returns  *empty* `IEnumerator<'b>` s

Comment: also `[] :> 'a seq` or `[||] :> 'a seq` or anything similiar ;)

Comment: The canon way of doing it can be seen [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L20-L59)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest implementation using sequence expressions I can think of is:

```
let empty() = seq { do () }
```

Or if you want a generic value rather than a function:

```
let empty<'T> : seq<'T> = seq { do () }
```

One would want to write just `seq { }` for a sequence expression that does not produce any values, but that's not syntactically valid and so we need to do *something* inside the sequence expression. Using `do ()` is just a way to tell the compiler that this is a syntactically valid sequence expression that does not do anything (and does not produce any values) when evaluated.